# spring boot is not reading correct property according profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, profile

My Spring boot application is started from the command line with the following parameters

> --spring.profiles.active=dev

Two property files are located in the resource folder :

> application.properties
>
> application_dev.properties

In my application I have a Spring Component which reads from the property file using the following

> @Value("${ch.admin.host}")
>
> private String remoteHost;

The problem is that the value of the default property file (application.properties) is assigned to the variable remoteHost, and not the value of the property file application_dev.properties

Comment: Should be application-dev.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your file to application-dev.properties.

Comment: I change the file name from application_dev.properties  to application-dev.properties, and it's working...many thanks